# Azure Machine Learning Compute quota?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

The [Manage and request quotas for Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-manage-quotas#azure-machine-learning-compute) documentation page states that the default quota depends "on your subscription offer type". The quota doesn't show up in Azure web portal. Is there a way to find out current quota values using SDK, CLI, REST API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to try something like this command :

```sh
az vm list-usage --location eastus --out table
```

It would get you the core usage for the region, which is what is important for deployment of resources.

Other choices (az + Powershell) are available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/networking/check-usage-against-limits).

Hope this helps!

Comment: The `az vm list-usage` is about common vm core quota. My question is about AML compute quota instead.

Comment: I misunderstood your question, sorry about that. The quota does show in the portal, if you navigate to one of your Azure ML Workspace, and on the left menu that appears under troubleshooting, you should see the "Usage + quotas" section. From there, you should see a subscription, and a per workspace view. These are indeed different quotas at the subscription level, for all services.

Comment: Is there a way to get the same info via javascript or REST API ? i.e. current quota availablity since cores are already in use.